# Why is the code giving Segmentaation fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I was solving the climbing leaderboard problem in hackerrank but my function gives segmentation fault.

```
vector<int> climbingLeaderboard(vector<int> scores, vector<int> alice) {
    vector<int> res,i;
    auto ip=  unique(scores.begin(),scores.begin()+scores.size());
    scores.resize(distance(scores.begin(),ip));
    for(int i =0;i<alice.size();++i)
    {
    int curr =0;
    while(alice[i]<=scores[curr]&&curr<scores.size())
    ++curr;
    
    if(alice[i]==scores[curr-1])
    res[i]=curr-1;
    else if(alice[i]>scores[curr])
    res[i]=curr;
    else if(curr>scores.size()-1)
    res[i]=curr; 
    
    
    
    }
    
    
    return res;
    
    }
```

It gives the following error:

```
> Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> #0  0x0000000000402a01 in climbingLeaderboard (scores=..., alice=...)
>     at /usr/local/include/c++/8.3.0/bits/stl_vector.h:930 930       operator[](size_type __n) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
```

Comment: Probably access out of bounds

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Comment: It's probable the problem is here: `while(alice[i]<=scores[curr]&&curr<scores.size())`. You should check the bounds first, then the data second, otherwise you'll access out of bounds and crash before you do your bounds check.

Comment: `if(alice[i]==scores[curr-1])` may be a bug as well. What happens if curr  is still 0 or is that impossible?

Comment: Thanks i fixed that, the problem was with res and checking the bounds before the data.

Comment: Consider enabling Wsign-conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, `res[i]` is accessed without allocating any elements in `res`.

`vector<int> res` should be `vector<int> res(alice.size())`.

Secondly, `scores[curr]` may be accessed before checking if `curr<scores.size()`.

```
    while(alice[i]<=scores[curr]&&curr<scores.size())
    ++curr;
```

should be

```
    while(curr<scores.size()&&alice[i]<=scores[curr])
    ++curr;
```

and

```
    else if(alice[i]>scores[curr])
    res[i]=curr;
    else if(curr>scores.size()-1)
    res[i]=curr;
```

should be

```
    else if(curr>scores.size()-1)
    res[i]=curr; 
    else if(alice[i]>scores[curr])
    res[i]=curr;
```

Comment: A bit of whitespace would make the code easier to read, too. And perhaps some references to avoid all the repetition...

Comment: @TedLyngmo It's only been half an hour. We don't need to pressure people into accepting answers so quickly. Cheers!